# Use Django's I18n functions with keys in the code instead of default English

Tags: django, internationalization, gettext, django-i18n

Is there a way to use Django's I18n features with keys in the code instead of storing the default language in the code and the others in .po/.mo files?

Something similar to Wikipedia, where the code has a "(whatlinkshere)" key that is translated in the English translation file as "What links here", in the French one as "Pages liées", etc.

I guess I could make "qqq" or "qqx" the default language and work from there, but then a person with a browser set in a non-managed language would see the keys instead of English.

The problem with having the English as default in the code is that if you make a slight adjustment to a string in English, the translation is lost altogether in the other language versions.

Comment: *"The problem with having the English as default in the code is that if you make a slight adjustment to a string in English, the translation is lost altogether in the other language versions."* — That is not really a problem. Using the proper gettext workflow, when you update source strings, you will *merge* the updated sources with the translations, and if the difference is small enough, this merge step will re-associate the translation with the new source string, possibly flagging it as "fuzzy". If the source string changed *significantly*, the translation probably should too.

Comment: You can use `LocaleMiddleware`. It will activate default language if there is no language information in incoming  request.